# Some questions about geodesic lamination

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups

I'm learning geodesic laminations on surfaces. Here are some questions I thought a lot but could not understand well.

We consider a complete finite area hyperbolic surface $S$ w/o geodesic boundary. A geodesic lamination is a closed subset in $S$ foliated by a disjoint union of (complete) geodesics called leaves. In general, it is a finite union of minimal laminations and isolated leaves.

**Question 1**: A minimal lamination either is a closed leaf(=a simple closed curve) or consists of uncountably many leaves, in which every leaf is dense. I can understand this, but I do not understand ***why even a half leaf is dense in a non-closed minimal lamination?***

A lamination $L$ without closed leaves is a disjoint union of non-closed minimal lamination. If we cut the surface along such a lamination (i.e. consider $S\setminus L$), we get finitely many components by area considerations. Each component can be completed to get a complete hyperbolic surface with geodesic boundary.

I "roughly" understand these statements. But I do not have a concrete example for this. I'm able to imagine a lamination with closed leaves and isolated leaves only. For example, we fix two simple closed curves and construct an infinite geodesic to spiral to them. For another example, I consider the surface of genus one with one cusp, we can cut along two infinite geodesics going up to the puncture neighbourhood. We get two ideal triangles.

**Question 2**. ***I think the same holds for the surface of genus 1 with one geodesic boundary, where the glue transformation for the "corners" of quadrilateral formed by two ideal triangles is a hyperbolic element***. Am I right?

**Question 3**. But I have no idea to think about a non-closed minimal lamination. Could anyone suggest a concrete example to think about? In Casson-Bleiler's book "automorphisms of surfaces after Nilsen and Thurston", the components of the complement of a lamination without closed leaves are either ideal polygons or union of crowns with a compact set. Is there a more direct way to understand the crowns on a surface?

Sorry for too many questions. Hope someone can correct me or point out some directions for me.

Comment: Are you familiar with constructions of laminations from train tracks and Cantor sets?

Comment: @DouglasZare: unfortunately no, could you point to me a reference for it?

Comment: Here is a brief introduction: http://www.ams.org/notices/200303/what-is-web.pdf A Cantor set has the nice property that it is homeomorphic to two disjoint copies of itself. This implies there is a natural way for a product of a train track with a Cantor set to be mapped to a lamination in the neighborhood of the train track in a mostly continuous fashion, with some gluing at the "switches."

Comment: @DouglasZare: thanks! Maybe I should understand more the train track.